# How to remove switchport mode access from Cisco Switch 2960?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios

This is in Cisco Packet Tracer - this is not a real switch.

Default interface config on Cisco Switch 2960 looks like this

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
```

Then I put it in `switchport mode access`

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport mode access
!
```

However, when I tried to remove it with `no switchport mode access`, I was getting the following error.

```
Switch#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Switch(config)#int f0/10
Switch(config-if)#no switchport mode access
Command rejected: An interface must be configured to the Access or Trunk    modes to be configured to NoNegotiate.
Switch(config-if)#
```

I've also tried `default interface f0/10` but didn't work

```
Switch(config)#default interface f0/10
Building configuration...
Command rejected: An interface must be configured to the Access or Trunk    modes to be configured to NoNegotiate.
   
Interface FastEthernet0/10 set to default configuration
Switch(config)#
Switch(config)#do sh run
...
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport mode access
!
...
```

What is the right way to remove `switchport mode access` from the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By right, you should be able to remove it with `no switchport mode access`.

However, when I test similar config on Packet Tracer, I'm getting exactly similar error message.

Are you using the actual switch (hardware) or Packet Tracer?

Anyway, here is how I solved it in Packet Tracer.

**Before**

```
Switch(config)#do sh run

!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
```

**Replicate issue**

```
Switch(config)#int f0/1
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access

Switch(config-if)#do sh run

!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport mode access
!
```

**Exactly similar issue!**

```
Switch(config-if)#int f0/1
Switch(config-if)#no switchport mode access
Command rejected: An interface must be configured to the Access or Trunk    modes to be configured to NoNegotiate.
Switch(config-if)#
```

**Solution in CPT**

```
Switch(config-if)#no switchport nonegotiate 
Switch(config-if)#no switchport mode access
Switch(config-if)#
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to up

Switch(config-if)#
```

**Verify it**

```
Switch(config-if)#do sh run

!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
```

Comment: It is Packet Tracer. He posted this question on Reddit and someone answered it there after guessing it was Packet Tracer.  I just edited the post to add that piece of text that would have made this a little easier.

Comment: Even if it does not actually say it is access, that is the default for the interface, so it will still be an access interface, A layer-2 interface must be access or trunk. You just found a bug to not show it. Not seeing it makes no difference, except to fool rookies because it is still an access interface.

Answer (score 5):

The default of a layer-2 switch interface on that switch model is `switchport mode access`. The interface is either an access or trunk interface, so you could use the `switchport mode trunk` to change the mode from access.

You can change it to a routed interface if you have enabled routing with the global `ip routing` command that allows you to use the interface `no switchport` command (no `mode access` or anything else on the command). That changes the interface from a layer-2 to a layer-3 interface, so access or trunk do not apply. You can then apply an ip address to the interface.

To convert back from a layer-3 to a layer-2 interface, you use the `switchport` interface command (nothing else on the command).

Comment: Thanks @Ron, I did try that but also getting similar error `Switch(config-if)#no switchport mode trunk
Command rejected: An interface must be configured to the Access or Trunk modes to be configured to NoNegotiate.
Switch(config-if)#`

Comment: As it says, and what I told you, it is either access or trunk for a layer-2 interface. If you want to disable that, you need to convert it to a layer-3 interface, but if it is a layer-2 interface, it must either be an access interface (default) or a trunk interface.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to the config prompt and type `default interface fa0/10` to reset the interface back its default configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse P., but that didn't work too. I've updated my post

Comment: @Wolf Interesting. I can't say I've ever noticed that on a 2960, personally.  Can I ask why you don't want to leave it in access mode?